# How to configure Elastic.Serilog.Sinks librari with appsettings.json?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, appsettings

I want to use `Elastic.Serilog.Sinks` library (created by Elastic co)
to submit logs to an Elastic instance inside the Elastic cloud.

How to configure logging using `appsettings.json` for a .NET 7 application?

How to configure authentication, Elastic server endpoint etc?

There is NO configuration example in the official documentation :(

Comment: Can only agree. Feels like a Hello World example...

Comment: Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch library does the job well. It is provided by Serilog community.